# I can list my messages , Listview

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I can list my messages, but now I wanted every message after that I had a balloon. To identify if I sent or received. The balloon is now the text is not staying. Can you help me?

```
<ListView x:Name="Post_List" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="2" Padding="5">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" OutlineColor="Transparent"
                        HasShadow="False" Grid.Column="0"
                        CornerRadius="5" BackgroundColor="#03A9F4">
                        <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Mensagem}"/>
                    </Frame>

                    <Label FontSize="Micro" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                        Text="{Binding Data}" TextColor="Gray"></Label>

                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image: My chat view]

[image: Similar with this]

Comment: which is the field you don't see? Data? Mensagem? Post your model

Comment: Mensagem dont field with frame. If i remove frame, mensagem appears

Comment: try adding a HeightRequest to the Label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `HasUnevenRows="True"` to your ListView will fix your issue.

This is because you did not set any `RowHeight` which is alright cause you want the height to be based on the content but the ListView does not know the dimension to apply. Using the `HasUnevenRows` the `ListView` will be calculating the size to fit the content.

```
<ListView x:Name="Post_List" Grid.Row="1" HasUnevenRows="True" >
<ListView.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate >
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="2" Padding="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Frame Grid.Row="0" OutlineColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" BackgroundColor="#03A9F4">
                    <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Mensagem}"/>
                </Frame>

                <Label FontSize="Micro" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Data}" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Hope this helps.-